# How to create a sign in method using firestore database and firebase authentication

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Hi im making a app with a register page where the user enters email, password, shared secret and then a sign in page. Using firestore i store the users shared secret which works fine. I also use the firebase authentication method for email and password. The issue i have is on the sign up page using the firebase authentication signInWithEmailAndPassword method i can only call the email and password. How would i go about checking the shared secret of the user as well as the email and password?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that I know how to do this is to add additional statements. I am assuming the shared secret is saved in the Realtime database. In this case, you are going to want to call that data and compare it to the user's input:

```
FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference secretRef; //before onCreate
private String currentUserId;
```

Now for your signin method

```
final EditText sharedSecret = findViewById(R.id.sharedSecret); //find user input
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
secretRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(currentUserId).child("sharedSecret");
final String checkedSecret = secretRef.toString();
```

Then you would compare it by using code like:

```
if(checkedSecret != sharedSecret)
{
//user is not login
}else{
//continue with login
}
```

Good luck

Comment: thank you, that seems like exactly what i need! however, im storing my data in firestore not the Realtime database

Answer (score 1):

When using email and password based sign-in, Firebase Authentication only lets you use that email and password pair to authenticate the user.  It has no concept of a shared secret.  If you want to check additional data, you will have to do that after the user is signed in, and decide what to do if the data doesn't match.

Comment: So would the process be something like Sign in page with email and pass which takes you to another page before getting access where you enter "shared secret" which gets checked against the one already stored in firestore for that user then if matches log in?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it. Essentially, once the new user enters a shared secret value, you check if that matches the one in the document. If it matches, you mark them as "verified" in the database (and probably clean up the shared secret).